# Why is the hermitian conjugate used whenever complex vectors are projected onto each other?

Tags: linear-algebra

Example:
Let $^\dagger$ be the hermitian and $^*$ be the complex conjugate:
In a proof that the eigenvectors of a normal matrix are orthogonal the final line reads: $$(\lambda_9-\lambda_j)(x^i)^{\dagger}x^j=0$$

How does $(x^i)^\dagger x^j$ equate to $x^i$ is orthogonal to $x^j$ instead of
$(x^i)^T x^j$

Comment: Because if $x$ lives in a complex vector space, the correct norm is $(x^*)^Tx$, i.e. the hermitian conjugate.

Comment: @Alex yes, but is there an easy way to understand why $(x^i)^\dagger x^j$ means the vectors are orthogonal and not $(x^i)^T x^j$ because the two values will be different. $(i,1)^T(i,-1)\ne0$ whereas $(i,1)^\dagger (i,-1)=0$. So it's not just convenience to get the right value of $\mid \mid x\mid \mid^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the inner product in complex vector spaces is usually $y^\dagger x$ because otherwise this wouldn't correctly define a norm ($\|x\|:=\sqrt{x^\dagger x})$. Consider $y^Tx$ instead. With your example of $x=(i,1)$, $x^Tx=-1+1=0$, which would imply $\|(i,1)\|=0$, but norms are allowed to 0 iff $(i,1)=(0,0)$. Worse still, $(2i,1)$ would have a negative norm.

Comment: I understand that the norm is wrong when you calculate it without the conjugate. I don't understand geometrically why the conjugate of a vector is orthogonal to a *different vector* means the original un-conjugated vector is orthogonal to the different vector. When you take a dot product it equals zero if the components are orthogonal, but in a complex space, it appears to equal zero when the conjugate of each component of one of the vectors is dot multipled. Why would that equal zero geometrically?

Comment: Because $i^2=-1$. Geometrically, the only thing that matters is the real magnitude of the vector components, but by just squaring the complex side length, it's gaining a -1 sign, hence you correct for it by conjugating.

Comment: aaah, now it makes sense. That's the answer there.